# Send user given Image to Api in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to take an image as input, which will be send to api as formData.

My code ->

For user input ->

```
            <input
              type="file"
              accept="image/*"
              name="image-upload"
              id="SelectFile"
              onChange={this.imageHandler}
              style={{ display: 'none' }}
            />
```

imageHandler function ->

```
  imageHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.files[0])
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(){
      const dataURL = reader.result;
      let output = document.getElementById('input');
      output.src = dataURL;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

    let form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('image', e.target.files[0]);
    saveImage(form_data,this.state.userDetail.email).then(res=>{
      if(res.success){
        this.setState({
          showAlert: true,
          alertMessage: 'Image Saved',
          alertType: 'success',
        });
      }
    })
  };
```

saveImage function calling the api ->

```
export const saveImage = async (data,email) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${commonApi.api}/user-image`, data, {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')
      },
      params:{
        userEmail: email
      }
    });
    if (response.data.success) {
      return { success: true, message: '', data: response.data.payload };
    } else {
      return { success: false, message: response.data.message };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('response',error.response.data)
    return { success: false, message: 'Failed' };
  }
};
```

So, this is throwing me an 403 error.
But when I am checking this with postman, it is working fine.

Postman request Image ->
https://ibb.co/HBxLWhn
So I am thinking I handled the image wrong.
What is the mistake I am making here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my problem after wasting over 2 hours. `authorization` in header is case sensitive it seems.
I wrote ->

```
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')
  },
```

Which should be ->

```
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')
  },
```

2 hours for an `A` xD